# UILabel border and padding

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add padding inside my label in order to have spaces between it and its border. I created for that a class that extends from UILabel.

UILabelPadding.swift:

```
import UIKit

class UILabelPadding: UILabel {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30)
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, padding))
    }

   override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        let superContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let width = superContentSize.width + padding.left + padding.right
        let heigth = superContentSize.height + padding.top + padding.bottom
        return CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let superSizeThatFits = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        let width = superSizeThatFits.width + padding.left + padding.right
        let heigth = superSizeThatFits.height + padding.top + padding.bottom
        return CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
    }


}
```

and I changed the type of myLabel from UILabel to UILabelPadding. In my UIViewController, I set the text of myLabel, call the sizeToFit() and after that I add the border and the background color to myLabel:

```
   myLabel.text = "label test"
   myLabel.sizeToFit()
    //background + border
    myLabel.layer.borderColor  = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 100/255, blue: 90/255,  alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    myLabel.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 100/255, blue: 90/255,  alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    myLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 9
    myLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    myLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

The border and the background color are added but the padding is not working. When I debug, the sizeThatFits() is never called.

Any help please?

Comment: try this way  myLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(LABEL_WIDTH, CGFLOAT_MAX))

Comment: I have to try this with the UILabel type? and what about the height?

Comment: I tested it and I got this error: cgsizemake unavailable in swift because I have the last version of Xcode (the 8.0 one)

Comment: it is swift3 myLabel.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: LABEL_WIDTH, height: CGFLOAT_MAX))

Comment: I got this "value of type uilabel has no member cgsize"

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I solved the issue!

For those how are facing the same problem:

1- Make a class extending from UILabel:

UILabelPadding.swift:

```
class UILabelPadding: UILabel {

    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 8, bottom: 2, right: 8)
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: padding))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
        let superContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
        let width = superContentSize.width + padding.left + padding.right
        let heigth = superContentSize.height + padding.top + padding.bottom
        return CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
    }



}
```

2- Set the type of your label to the UILabelPadding and make sure that the type is set also in the storyboard.

Comment: but when used your code then my label height not set as per text , label text cut off as per padding

Comment: @NidhiPatel you set the height property to fixed value, remove it so then your label height will be adjusted

Comment: Oh, you saved me ! Great described ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks. FYI, if you set the padding as var you can set it from within your views.

Comment: Superrrrrrrrrr :)

Answer (score 5):

I use a label subclass that does much what you describe. It looks like this:

```
class MyBoundedLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.stroke(self.bounds.insetBy(dx: 1.0, dy: 1.0))
        super.drawText(in: rect.insetBy(dx: 5.0, dy: 5.0))
    }
}
```

You might try that, and then jiggle the numbers and other details so they look like what you want.

Comment: can you please tell me what is dx and dy?

Comment: There is nothing to tell. This is code that just works out of the box. These are all built-in methods.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? I assure you that it does work. I would have to suggest that perhaps your label is not a MyBoundedLabel. The code comes from here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk1ch10p418subclassing That is a downloadable project that you can just download and run, yourself, on your own machine, and you will see with your own eyes that it _does_ work.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution in my app. Please check below codes.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {
        
        var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
            didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
        }
        
        override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
            let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
            let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
                                              left: -textInsets.left,
                                              bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
                                              right: -textInsets.right)
            return textRect.inset(by: invertedInsets)
        }
        
        override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
            super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: textInsets))
        }
    }
```